# Change item background on RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background, touch

I want to make clickable item of my `RecyclerView`. However it is not working. `item_background.xml` is defined well, it works in other parts of my project. However in this case, I have more items in `LinearLayout`, which contain some `onClick` listeners. When I click on an `item`, background is not changed. Please see the code below.

I cannot set background for inside items instead, because I need the whole item to change background color, not only parts.

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/item_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    ...
    >

    <TextView
        <!-- NO BACKGROUND -->
        ... />

    <ImageView
        <!-- NO BACKGROUND -->
        ... />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

item_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Are you getting the click? Try logging something onClick

Comment: @Tom11 please mention your adapter code here.

Comment: try using the android default for this behaviour: `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @abraham-mathew Onclick works as expected.

Comment: @luciano-ferruzzi tried, not working - color is not changed on item touch.

Comment: @pankaj-mundra Does adapter have something with this? OnClick works, only color is not changing on item touch.

Comment: please share your Fragment/Activity code!

Comment: @Tom11 Where have you mentioned the color change code. i.e on Activity/Fragment or inside Adapter. Please mention your onClick code here.

Answer (score 1):

To change the background or highlight the selected item in `recyclerview` you can try this

```
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder> {
        private int selected_position = -1;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PlacesLocationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (selected_position == position) {
                // do your stuff here like
                //Change selected item background 
               parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("darkgraycolorcode"));

            } else {
                  // do your stuff here like
                  //Change  unselected item background 
                   parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
  // rest of the code here

    holder.linelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              if(selected_position==position){
                        selected_position=-1;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return;
                    }
                    selected_position = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    //rest of the code here

     }


}
```

Also you can define the parent layout click listener ie linearlayout in view holder also